# How to move text on canvas horizontally straight line?

Tags: android, canvas, text, draw, move

I have took text on canvas applying rotation on it. Now I want to move the text horizontally but it's moving on cross. For rotation i have done something like below.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(-45,150,150);
canvas.drawText("Some Text", xAxis, 55, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

It's not moving straight because of the rotation applied to the whole canvas. Now I want this text to move horizontally straight line.

Is there any way around?

The output of the above code is like this

[image: output of above code]

Right not if I increase the value of `xAxis` it's moving like the line red. I want it to move like line green in the picture.

Comment: `translate()` it before `rotate()`

Comment: @pskink can you suggest me how? Actually didn't get you

Comment: see `Canvas` documentation about `translate` and `rotate` methods

Comment: @pskink tried but no luck

Comment: so where you failed?

Comment: @pskink I have applied `canvas.translate(150,150);` before `canvas.rotate(-45,150,150);` so no effect!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133805/discussion-between-android-griezmann-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you rotated whole `Canvas` itself. Imagine you rotate your screen 45 degrees and move mouse horizontally - it will move with that rotation. You need another approach to rotate text, or you'll be needed to calculate move point depending on rotation angle (rotate point around point).

Comment: I know why text moving 45 degree. Can you suggest me solution for that?

Comment: Create bitmap and canvas(second canvas), draw on second canvas (it will draw on bitmap), and then `first_canvas.drawBitmap()`. This way you can place bitmap wherever you want.